# Find parent directory recursively

Tags: directory, parent

I am writing a script which requires me to find the parent directory of the existing directory.
Suppose I have a directory called deep which is under `/path/is/very/deep/`. I need to find the "path" directory but not "/".

Tried couple of combination of code but seems I am stuck in a dead lock.

Appreciate any help.

here is my code which is not working.

```
if [ $dir_name != "/"  || $path != "/" ]
then
path=`dirname $dir_name`
dir_name=`dirname $path`
echo $path
else
dir_name=$path
echo $dirname
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an alternative way to solve your problem:

Generally all you need to do is to remove all characters in the string after (and including) the second `/` character. Linux Terminals have the sed function that allows you to do it.

try out this line in your `Terminal/code`:

```
echo '/path/is/very/deep' | sed  -r 's:^(/[^/]*).*$:\1:'
```

you can remove the echo command and assign it to any variable in your code as you wish.
Edit: In sed the backslash (/) is also used as a delimiter character, you have to escape it with a forward slash (\). Parentheses are also escaped for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
path="$( echo "${dir_name}" | sed -e 's|/[^/]*/\{0,1\}$||;s|^$|/|' )"
```

(posix compliant) and work for /, /bla, /bla/, bla/bla, ...